# Reduce with seed an array of strings

Tags: functional-programming, d

Is it possible to perform `std.algorithm.reduce` with the seed being an array of strings? Something like this:

```d
reduce!(string[], (r,c) => r ~= c)([], someIterable);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, but due to the nature of dynamic arrays you have to declare it first:

```d
string[] arr;
reduce!((r, c) => r~=c)(arr, someIterable);
```

Comment: Or the one line version: `reduce!((r, c) => r~=c)(string[].init, someIterable);`